# After enabling HTTPS for a Nexus Container, CURL upload/downloads error out with the following error: curl: 51 SSL: no alternative certificate

Tags: curl, containers, nexus, tls1.2

I'm running into an issue when I enable HTTPS for a Nexus Container (v3:3.30.0), I am not longer able to upload/download artifacts via Curl, however the web UI does come up via HTTPS.  I'm getting the following error when trying to curl:  curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject matches target host name

I'm using keytool to generate .jks and .pem files.  Then the .pem is imported to a internal Active Directory Certificate Services.  Once the certificate chain is generated, I import them back into the keystore on the container, along with following best practices from Sonatype on other configurations.

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/system-configuration/configuring-ssl

I restart the container and can reach the UI via HTTPS, but curl now shows the following error:

[user_a@host_a]$ curl -l -v https://10.88.0.255:8081

```
Rebuilt URL to: https://10.88.0.255:8081/
  Trying 10.88.0.255...
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to 10.88.0.255 (10.88.0.255) port 8081 (#0)
ALPN, offering h2
ALPN, offering http/1.1
successfully set certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
Server certificate:
 subject: C=XX; ST=XX; L=XXXXXXXX; O=XX-XX; OU=XXX; CN=xxxx-xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com
 start date: Nov 28 19:49:21 2021 GMT
 expire date: Nov 28 19:49:21 2023 GMT
 subjectAltName does not match 10.88.0.255
    SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name '10.88.0.255'*
Closing connection 0
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name '10.88.0.255'


Any of the openssl commands that I use against the container

openssl s_client –connect 10.88.1.9:8081 

openssl s_client -connect 10.88.1.9:8081 --showcerts

openssl s_client -connect 10.88.1.9:8081 -tlsextdebug 

openssl s_client -connect 10.88.1.9:8081 -tls1_2
```

Come back with

---

### SSL handshake has read 4590 bytes and written 328 bytes
Verification: OK

Verify return code: 0 (ok)

Comment: Is the 'web UI' (I assume in a browser) using the address or a domain name? Whatever name works in a browser should work in curl. BTW it's "alternative certificate subject _name_" -- the name can have an alternative, not the certificate; specifically the certificate contains the SubjectAlternativeName extension, abbreviated SubjectAltName, SubjAltName, or just SAN.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to work, not sure if this is correct or not, but its working...

The SAN=DNS entries that I used to generate the cert request, I placed into /etc/hosts along with the IP addressed assigned to the container (running Podman, and the container as rootfull).

Once doing this, able to use curl against those SAN=DNS entries along with launching the Nexus Web UI by those entries too.